Proving an equivalence about probability measures on a space.
Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $T :X \to X$ a measurable transformation and $\mu,\nu$ probability measures on $(X,\mathcal{A})$. Prove TFAE:
(i) $\nu(T^{-1}(E))=\mu(E)$ for all $E \in \mathcal{A}$.
(ii) $\int \phi d \mu = \int \phi \circ T d \nu$ for all $\phi \in L^1(\mu)$.
Attempt:
For the forward direction, letting $\phi \in L^1(\mu)$, I define a function
$$\psi:X \to \Bbb{R}$$
via $\psi(x)=\phi(T(x))$ for every $x \in X$. Then it suffices to prove $\int \phi d \mu = \int \psi d \nu$ and $\psi$ is clearly measurable as it is the composition of measurable functions. I need to also show $\psi \in L^1(\mu)$ right? Does it follow that
$$\int_E \vert \psi \vert d \nu = \int_{T^{-1}(E)} \vert \phi \vert d \nu = \nu(T^{-1}(E))=\mu(E).$$
Where the first equality is by change of variables and assumption of (i) and the last equality holds by just (i).  Am I on the right track?
For the backwards direction should I consider as my $\phi$ just $\chi_E$ the indicator function on $E$? Then by assumption of (ii) we have
$$\int \chi_E d \mu = \int \chi_E \circ T d \nu.$$
If this is the case I see the LHS is just $\mu(E)$ and I need to play with the RHS to get $\nu(T^{-1}(E))$.

This boils down to check things on simple functions and then use the fact that they are dense in $L^1$. Note that $\chi_E\circ T = \chi_{T^{-1}(E)}$ as $\chi_E(Tx)=1$ iff $Tx\in E$ iff $x\in T^{-1}(E)$ iff $\chi_{T^{-1}(E)}(x)=1$.

The key observation is that
$$ \chi_{E}\circ T = \chi_{T^{-1}(E)}. $$
Indeed we have
$$ \chi_E(Tx) = \begin{cases} 1,& Tx\in E,\\ 0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
= \begin{cases} 1,& x\in T^{-1}(E),\\ 0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
=\chi_{T^{-1}(E)}(x). $$
This takes care of the direction $ii.) \Rightarrow i.)$ as
$$ \nu(T^{-1}(E))= \int \chi_{T^{-1}(E)} d\nu = \int \chi_E \circ T d\nu = \int \chi_E d\mu = \mu(E). $$
For the other direction we use the argument in reverse to get that
$$ \int \chi_E \circ T d\nu = \int \chi_E d\mu. $$
By linearity this yields
$$ \int \varphi \circ T d\nu = \int \varphi d\mu $$
for all simple functions $\varphi$. Then we can pass through the usual construction, namely, we can use dominated convergence to prove it for all nonnegative $L^1$ functions and then by linearity we get it for all $L^1$ functions.
